# Setting an attribute used by JSLint JavaScript code in RhinoUnit

Tags: javascript, ant, rhino, jslint, rhino-unit

I am trying to use [RhinoUnit](http://code.google.com/p/rhinounit/) for unit testing of a standalone, XUL-based JavaScript app. I have successfully altered a lot of paths in the given `build.xml` - mostly changing paths to RhinoUnit scripts, which I prefer to put in another directory than the default one (that is, I put RhinoUnit files in `chrome/content/rhino` and JSLint files in `chrome/content/lint`). On some moment, however, I've got this error:

```
/<project-path>/build.xml:52: javax.script.ScriptException: 
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /<project-path>/jslint/fulljslint.js
(No such file or directory) (<Unknown source>#31) in <Unknown source>
at line number 31
```

There is no reference to `jslint/fulljslint.js` in the `build.xml`, but I have found this code at `jslintant.js`:

```js
var jsLintPath = "jslint/fulljslint.js";
if (attributes.get("jslintpath")) {
    jsLintPath = attributes.get("jslintpath");
}
```

It looked to me that this code sets a default value to the variable and then try to use the value from some `attributes` object. I am supposing these `attributes` can be set outside the script, through e.g. some `<atttribute />` tag int `build.xml` or some configuration file.

My question is: how could I change the value from the object? Is that possible? Or should I change the hardcoded string from the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility to consider.

*How to figure out what's going on:*
If you insert this in the `jslintant.js` file, just prior to the jsLintPath assignment you mention:

```
echo = project.createTask( "echo" );
echo.setMessage( attributes );
echo.perform( );
```

Then run the RhinoUnit build, you should see something like:

```
run-js-lint:
     [echo] {options={eqeqeq : false, white: true, plusplus : false, bitwise :  ... }}
```

***How to do what you want:***  The 'options' are defned as an attribute of the `jslintant` scriptdef.  To propagate a value for jslintpath, you need to add it as an attribute in the scriptdef, then set it when you use the task so defined.  For example:

```
<scriptdef name="jslintant"
           src="jslint/jslintant.js"
           language="javascript">
    <attribute name="options" />
    <attribute name="jslintpath" /> <!-- This line added. -->
    <element name="fileset" type="fileset" />
</scriptdef>
```

then use the task:

```
<jslintant options="{eqeqeq : false, ... }"
           jslintpath="your_path_here/fulljslint.js" />
```

If you rerun the build, you should then see:

```
run-js-lint:
     [echo] {jslintpath=your_path_here/fulljslint.js, options={eqeqeq : false, ... }}
```

And the path you chose will be used to find `fulljslint.js`.